# Beautiful Soup Value not extracting properly

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Recently i was working with python beautiful soup to extract some data and put it into pandas DataFrame.
I used python beautiful soup to extract some of the hotel data from the website booking.com.
I was able to extract some of the attributes very correctly without any empty.
Here is my code snippet:

```
def get_Hotel_Facilities(soup):
    try:
        title = soup.find_all("div", attrs={"class":"db29ecfbe2 c21a2f2d97 fe87d598e8"})
        new_list = []
        # Inner NavigatableString Object
        for i in range(len(title)):
          new_list.append(title[i].text.strip())

    except AttributeError:
       new_list=""

    return new_list
```

**The above code is my function to retrieve the Facilities of a hotel and return the facilitites List items.**

```
page_no=0
d = {"Hotel_Name":[], "Hotel_Rating":[], "Room_type":[],"Room_price":[],"Room_sqft":[],"Facilities":[],"Location":[]}
while (page_no<=25):
     URL = f"https://www.booking.com/searchresults.html?aid=304142&label=gen173rf-1FCAEoggI46AdIM1gDaGyIAQGYATG4ARfIAQzYAQHoAQH4AQKIAgGiAg1wcm9qZWN0cHJvLmlvqAIDuAKwwPadBsACAdICJDU0NThkNDAzLTM1OTMtNDRmOC1iZWQ0LTdhOTNjOTJmOWJlONgCBeACAQ&sid=2214b1422694e7b065e28995af4e22d9&sb=1&sb_lp=1&src=theme_landing_index&src_elem=sb&error_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.booking.com%2Fhotel%2Findex.html%3Faid%3D304142%26label%3Dgen173rf1FCAEoggI46AdIM1gDaGyIAQGYATG4ARfIAQzYAQHoAQH4AQKIAgGiAg1wcm9qZWN0cHJvLmlvqAIDuAKwwPadBsACAdICJDU0NThkNDAzLTM1OTMtNDRmOC1iZWQ0LTdhOTNjOTJmOWJlONgCBeACAQ%26sid%3D2214b1422694e7b065e28995af4e22d9%26&ss=goa&is_ski_area=0&checkin_year=2023&checkin_month=1&checkin_monthday=13&checkout_year=2023&checkout_month=1&checkout_monthday=14&group_adults=2&group_children=0&no_rooms=1&b_h4u_keep_filters=&from_sf=1&offset{page_no}"
     new_webpage = requests.get(URL, headers=HEADERS)
     soup = BeautifulSoup(new_webpage.content,"html.parser")
     links = soup.find_all("a", attrs={"class":"e13098a59f"})
     for link in links:
        new_webpage = requests.get(link.get('href'), headers=HEADERS)
        new_soup = BeautifulSoup(new_webpage.content, "html.parser")
        d["Hotel_Name"].append(get_Hotel_Name(new_soup))
        d["Hotel_Rating"].append(get_Hotel_Rating(new_soup))
        d["Room_type"].append(get_Room_type(new_soup))
        d["Room_price"].append(get_Price(new_soup))
        d["Room_sqft"].append(get_Room_Sqft(new_soup))
        d["Facilities"].append(get_Hotel_Facilities(new_soup))
        d["Location"].append(get_Hotel_Location(new_soup))

     page_no += 25
```

**The above code is the main one where the while loop will traverse the linked pages and retrieve the URL's of the pages. After retrieving ,it goes to every page to retrieve the corresponding atrributes.**

I was able to retrieve the rest of the attributes correctly but i am not able to retrive the facilities, Like only some of the room facilities are being returned and some are not returning.

**Here is my below o/p after making it into a pandas data frame.**
[Facilities o/p image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Iivz.jpg)

Please help me in this Problem as why some are coming and some are not coming.

**P.S:- The facilities are available in the website**

I have Tried using all the corresponding classes and attributes for retrieval but i am not getting the facilities column properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably as a predictive measure, the html fetched by the requests don't seem to consistent in their layouts or even the contents.

There might be more possible [`selectors`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors), but try

```py
def get_Hotel_Facilities(soup):
    selectors = ['div[data-testid="property-highlights"]', '#facilities', 
                 '.hp-description~div div.important_facility']
    new_list = []
    for sel in selectors:
        for sect in soup.select(sel): 
            new_list += list(sect.stripped_strings)
    return list(set(new_list)) # set <--> unique
```

But even with this, the results are inconsistent. E.g.: I tested on [this page](https://www.booking.com/hotel/in/country-inn-tarika-varca-beach-goa.ja.html?aid=304142&label=gen173rf-1FCAEoggI46AdIM1gDaGyIAQGYATG4ARfIAQzYAQHoAQH4AQKIAgGiAg1wcm9qZWN0cHJvLmlvqAIDuAKwwPadBsACAdICJDU0NThkNDAzLTM1OTMtNDRmOC1iZWQ0LTdhOTNjOTJmOWJlONgCBeACAQ&sid=18ea2a50fe267f571c434ec1d16b784c&all_sr_blocks=902383602_366379939_2_41_0;checkin=2023-01-13;checkout=2023-01-14;dist=0;group_adults=2;group_children=0;hapos=1;highlighted_blocks=902383602_366379939_2_41_0;hpos=1;matching_block_id=902383602_366379939_2_41_0;no_rooms=1;req_adults=2;req_children=0;room1=A%2CA;sb_price_type=total;sr_order=popularity;sr_pri_blocks=902383602_366379939_2_41_0__800000;srepoch=1673556447;srpvid=5798922f46230054;type=total;ucfs=1&#hotelTmpl) with

```py
for i in range(10):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(cloudscraper.create_scraper().get(url).content)
    fl = get_Hotel_Facilities(soup) if soup else []
    print(f'[{i}] {len(fl)} facilities: {", ".join(fl)}')
```

[image: test]

(But the inconsistencies might be due to using cloudscraper - maybe you'll get better results with your headers?)

Comment: So using the above selectors may solve my problem?

Comment: @BODDAPALLIKOUSHIK somewhat. Like I said, the site seems to be rotating through various html structures. My `selectors` list accounts for 3 of them but if there are more, those might still yield empty lists